# Google Sheet Script needed to Link a cell value to Google drive folder matching *.pdf file

Tags: javascript

[image]I want to link a cell value to view a matching *.pdf file in google drive based on cell value.

I found this code to possibly adapt:

```
var range = activeSheet.getRange(2, 1, activeSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1); 
//A2:A8
var invoiceNumbers = range.getValues();
var nameUrl = {}; //Object to hold name and Url
/*Fill the nameUrl*/
while (files.hasNext()) {
var file = files.next();
var fullname = file.getName();
var url = file.getUrl();
nameUrl[fullname] = url;
}
var links = invoiceNumbers.map(function(e) {
return [
'=HYPERLINK("' + nameUrl['Invoice-' + e[0] + '.pdf'] + '","' + e[0] + 
'")'
```

];});range.setValues(links);

So if "Ingress: 8" would link to "Bus Routes/Bus 8 Ingress.pdf" in Google drive. (See screenshot) The value in the cell can be from "1" to "46"

Comment: The script was copied from a similar post, it does not work with my sheet but does the same thing. I do not know how to modify it to work..

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you explain about ``it does not work``? And also, I cannot understand about your Spreadsheet.

Comment: In my spreadsheet shown above - Ingress: 8 (The number "8" is in cell E17)

E17 now has a new formula I just added  =CONCATENATE("Bus ",C13," Ingress") - Now E17 shows "Bus 8 Ingress"
The file name in Google Drive is "Bus 8 Ingress.pdf" 
I want a link to this pdf file to view it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. There is a value of ``Bus 8 Ingress`` at the cell "E17" in your Spreadsheet. I could understand like this. Is the cell you want to use only "E17"? And can I ask you about the issue of your current script? If I misunderstood your situation, please tell me.

Comment: I want to use E17 "Bus 8 Ingress" to link to Google Drive file "Bus 8 Ingress.pdf"
E18 "Bus 8 Egress" to link to Google Drive file "Bus 8 Egress.pdf"

I need a new script to do this the one above is no good.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal. You want to retrieve just 2 values from 2 cells "E17" and "E18". You want to retrieve the view links from files of the filename adding the extension of ``.pdf``. If my understanding is correct, what do you want to do the retrieved links? By the way, I cannot find the values of ``Bus 8 Ingress`` and ``Bus 8 Egress`` in your image. How about this? And I couldn't understand the issue of script from ``no good``. Is there an error? This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this.

Comment: The image file is old.
The goal is to click on E17 & E18 and view the pdf file.

Comment: Thank you for replying. 1. You want to open the PDF files with the links in the cells ("E17" and E18"). About this, I could correctly understand. 2. Can I ask you about the method for executing the script? You want to run it by the script editor? 3. Your question includes old information. I could understand like this. Can you update your question by including the latest information of your goal? I think that it will help users including me think of your issue and solution.

Comment: 2. When the cell value changes the script would update the link.

Comment: Thank you for updating the image. You said ``The goal is to click on E17 & E18 and view the pdf file.`` at the comment. But when I saw your updated image, I cannot think of that "Bus 43 Ingress" and "Bus 43 Egress" is put in "E17" and "E18". So I cannot understand about what you want to do. Can you explain about the detail information of it? About your additional request, I think that you can use OnEdit event trigger. Please check [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/).

Comment: Image is correct updated..
Cell E17 "BUS 43 Ingress" links to BUS 43 Ingress.pdf in drive folder
Cell E19 "Bus 43 Egress" links to BUS 43 Egress.pdf in drive folder